# Weird Ethernet behavior when switching SD card between Pi 3's

Tags: pi-3, networking, sd-card, ethernet, jessie-lite

I've got a number of Raspberry Pi 3 Model B's running Raspbian-Jessie-Lite (2017-04-10) that I've been trying to test switching the micro SD card between. I can have a Pi up and working perfectly and then replace it exactly with another Pi 3 and the Ethernet stops working. Everything else seemingly works fine.

With the Pi connected to a gigabit switch, the Pi will identify as 100M when working correctly. When switching to another Pi, it typically doesn't bring the interface up at all (according to the switch - although ifconfig reports it does) or it comes up as 10M (again - according to the switch).

As per the suggestion [here](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Networking_no_longer_works_when_changing_SD_card_between_two_Raspberry_Pis), I checked /etc/udev/rules.d/ but didn't see a 70-persistent-net.rules file. It would seem that something unique to each particular piece of hardware (like a MAC address) might be getting set somewhere in the OS and causing issues. Is there anywhere else I should check to see if the address is being set or any other suggestions?

Comment: What kind of switch are you connected to? It could be an arp cache issue...

Comment: I've tried a number of different switches - Netgear GS108, Dualcomm DCSW-1005, Dualcomm ETAP-2105, as well as hardwiring directly into a laptop. I suspect you might be right with it being an ARP issue, but how would I begin checking into that?

Comment: Well, on higher-end brand switches, you can manually clear the arp cache (`clear arp-cache` on Cisco for example), but the lower end ones, perhaps just a switch reboot after turning off Pi 1 and before powering up Pi 2 should let you know if arp cache is an issue. Also, are you using DHCP? Do you have any special configurations or limitations related to MAC addresses to IP address assignment?